# TF/Keras 'import_from_directory' resulting in directory NotFoundError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am pre-processing data for my CNN in Tensorflow/Keras. I am using the [**image_dataset_from_directory**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) method to fetch the data from a specified directory:

```
dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(data, seed=123,
    shuffle=True,
    image_size=(IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

But it is not is not fetching the data from the directory, and instead gives a directory **NotFoundError**:

```
NotFoundError           Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(data, seed=123,
    shuffle=True,
    image_size=(IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

**Screenshot**:

[image: Screenshot of error]

I tried to rectify the error by manually specifying the path of the data, but the error persists. How can I correctly determine the data path for the `image_dataset_from_directory` function?

Or are there any other possible suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

`image_dataset_from_directory` is not function of the Keras `preprocessing` package, but of the `utils` package.

You simply need to replace your call with `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory`.

Doc: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory